# Update an array using a property : Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having a selected object that has the following structure

```
const selected = [
  { field: { prop1: "value1" }, isDeleted: true, isSelected: false },
  { field: { prop1: "value2" }, isDeleted: true, isSelected: false },
  { field: { prop1: "value3" }, isDeleted: false, isSelected: false }
];
```

Also I am having current objects with the following structure

```
const current = [
  { field: { prop1: "value2" }, isDeleted: false, isSelected: false },
  { field: { prop1: "value1" }, isDeleted: false, isSelected: false }
];
```

Now basically I have return appended list with remaining objects that has `isDeleted: true` in current, and then take the objects of `selected` that has `isDeleted: true` and append to the current, with `isDeleted: false` i sequence of its presence in `selected`

For the above input the output will be,

```
const output = [
  { field: { prop1: "value3" }, isDeleted: false, isSelected: false },
  { field: { prop1: "value2" }, isDeleted: false, isSelected: false },
  { field: { prop1: "value1" }, isDeleted: false, isSelected: false }
];
```

As the object in current with field `prop1` has `isDeleted :false`, so that becomes the first object. And remaining objects of `current` are matched with `selected` to find a match using name and `isDeleted: true` and adding it to the output, with its `isDeleted` changing to `false`.

Code that I tried

```
const selected = [
  { field1: { prop1: "value1" }, isDeleted: true, isSelected: false },
  { field1: { prop1: "value2" }, isDeleted: true, isSelected: false },
  { field1: { prop1: "value3" }, isDeleted: false, isSelected: false }
];

const current = [
  { field1: { prop1: "value1" }, isDeleted: false, isSelected: false },
  { field1: { prop1: "value2" }, isDeleted: false, isSelected: false }
];
const selectedModified = selected.map((sel) => {
  const found = current.find(
    (cur) => cur.field.prop1 === sel.field.prop1 && sel.isDeleted
  );
  if (found) {
    return {
      field: sel.field,
      isDeleted: false,
      isSelected: false
    };
  }
  return sel;
});
const filtered = [...(selectedModified || []), ...current].filter(
  filterBy("prop1")
);
const filterBy = (key, set = new Set()) => (o) =>
!set.has(o.file[key]) && set.add(o.file[key]);
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't that just be: concatenating the two arrays and filtering the result for `isDeleted === false`?

```js
const selected = [
  { field: { prop1: "value1" }, isDeleted: true, isSelected: false },
  { field: { prop1: "value2" }, isDeleted: true, isSelected: false },
  { field: { prop1: "value3" }, isDeleted: false, isSelected: false }
];
const current = [
  { field: { prop1: "value2" }, isDeleted: false, isSelected: false },
  { field: { prop1: "value1" }, isDeleted: false, isSelected: false }
];

const output = selected.concat(current).filter(v => !v.isDeleted);
document.querySelector(`pre`).textContent = JSON.stringify(output, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```